# How to add new column in my test_set datafram?

Tags: python, deep-learning, data-science, data-analysis

How  to add  `true_prediction` variable to the test data

```
test['prediction'] = true_prediction
```

but it's not added as a new column, as shown in [myresult_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujjmn.png.)

How to make the test data accept it as a new column!!

Comment: what is the output for this line : `print(type(test))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be 'test' is not a dataframe?

Try:

```py
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
test['prediction'] = true_prediction
```